# Capitalize entries using ASP.NET client side validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am using the typical validator controls for required fields etc. On this form, the requirement is to transform the text to ALL CAPS as the user is entering their data. Again, no problem. However, once validation occurs, if there is an error, the data the user has entered thus far is repopulated in the form in the case in which it was entered - usually a mixture of upper and lower case. How do I force the text in the form to be repopulated in all upper case? Is there a client-side validation event I can use (since it all happens in the client side, there is no postback at this point)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need all details to be in upper case, just let the user enter them in whichever form they wish. You can just use CSS to give the appearance of this being in uppercase:

```
text-transform:uppercase;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JwjeH/1/

---

Then server-side, you can simply call `txtMyTextBox.Text.ToUpper()` to convert the string.

Otherwise, if you rely on the client side, if they have javascript turned off for example, you may find lower case strings entering your system.

Comment: Yes, I can transform the text easily after they enter it (and while they enter it using the CSS you mentioned) and store it as upper case, that's no problem. However, I also need to re-display it in upper case if the form validation finds an error prior to postback.

Comment: @Earl Have you tried adding the CSS I suggested? That will do just that.

Comment: +1: This is a better solution as casing will be restricted from the start.

Comment: Yes, I have. It works when the user first enters the data. The problem I'm having is this: Let's say a user enters an incorrectly formed email and the regex validator catches this and prevents the form from submitting. The email address is currently displayed in all caps. However, once the validator displays the error message, the email address is now displayed in lower case. Somehow the validator triggers the form to be re-populated without a postback and the CSS doesn't catch it and re-transform it.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. It works now. Previous styles must have been cached. Thanks, @Curt.